Do Ubuntu 24.04 Raspberry Pi Desktop Camera and Cheese apps support Raspberry Pi Camera v2 or v3?
It appears that the Raspberry Pi v2 or v3 CSI Camera are not supported by this new Raspberry Pi controller running Ubuntu Desktop 24.04, a disappointment as it works on Raspberry Pi 4 running Ubuntu 22.04.
Assigning $USER permission to video, when either RPi CSI Camera or USB C525 Webcam are plugged in separately, shows as crw-rw----+ 1 root video 81, 18 Dec 15 14:05 /dev/video0, but the Camera app (executable Snapshot) has a error message: Camera not Available i.e. cannot display either camera image. The Cheese app displays the USB camera but not the RPi camera. In /boot/firmware/config.txt I use config_autodetect=1. If I use config_autodetect=0 no camera shows in /dev/video0. On investigation, I discovered that the library used is BCM2711 which is different than the one in a Raspberry Pi 4 that uses the BCM2835 library, where the RPi Camera works correctly.
